# Is it integration or not

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, approximate-integration

I was solving a physics problem and I encountered to find the sum the function $xe^{-kx}$ where for all positive values of $x$ (i.e. from 0 to infinity)  Is there any way to do that?

I speculate that the sum will be equal to the integral of function with same limits.  If it is true, can you please give me an idea of how does it relate to integrals. If I am right its not the Riemann sum form because that involves multiplication with "${\rm d}x$"

Edit: [image: question]

[image: my attempt to the solution]

Comment: It is a Function of x

Comment: I do not have details that is why I am asking this question here

Comment: give details of problem and your solution.

Comment: @Arjang See the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-kx}dx=-\left.\frac{x}{k}e^{-kx}\right]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx}dx=\frac{1}{k^2}$$ which can be seen by integration by parts and De L´Hospital´s rule.